# Aframe movement control on mobile phone regarding to twoway-motion.js

Tags: javascript, android, ios, aframe, webvr

I am testing twoway-motion.js on Aframe, by providing a simple way to navigate specifically **without a device orientation permission** from a mobile phone.

please check this glitch page for details: https://glitch.com/~scrawny-efraasia

also please see twoway-motion.js by @flowerio

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('twoway-motion', {
schema: {
    speed: { type: "number", default: 40 },
    threshold: { type: "number", default: -40 },
    nonMobileLoad: { type: "boolean", default: false },
    removeCheckpoints: {type: "boolean", default: true },
    chatty: {type: "boolean", default: true }
},
init: function () {
    var twowaymotion = document.querySelector("[camera]").components["twoway-motion"];
    twowaymotion.componentName = "twoway-motion";
    report = function(text) {
        if (twowaymotion.data.chatty) {
            console.log(twowaymotion.componentName, ":", text); 
        }
    }

    report("init."); 
    // report("asked to load with speed=", this.data.speed);

    if (!AFRAME.utils.device.isMobile() && this.data.nonMobileLoad === false) {
        // this is only for mobile devices.
        //document.querySelector("[camera]").removeAttribute("twoway-motion");
        report("Retired. Will only work on mobile.");
        return;
    } else {
        if (this.data.nonMobileLoad === true) {
            report("Loading on non-mobile platform.");
        }
    }

    if (this.el.components["wasd-controls"] === undefined) {
        this.el.setAttribute("wasd-controls", "true");
        report("Installing wasd-controls.");
    }
    this.el.components["wasd-controls"].data.acceleration = this.data.speed;

    // two-way hides checkpoint-controls by default.
    if (this.data.removeCheckpoints) {
        if (this.el.components["checkpoint-controls"] !== undefined) {
            var checkpoints = document.querySelectorAll("[checkpoint]");
            for (var cp = 0; cp < checkpoints.length; cp++) {
                checkpoints[cp].setAttribute("visible", false);
            }
        }
    }

    this.el.removeAttribute("universal-controls");
    if (this.el.components["look-controls"] === undefined) {
        this.el.setAttribute("look-controls", "true");
    }

    var cur = document.querySelector("[cursor]");
    if (cur !== null) {
        console.log(this.componentName, ": found a cursor.");
        this.cur = cur;
        //this.curcolor = cur.getAttribute("material").color;
        this.curcolor = cur.getAttribute("color");
    } else {
        console.log(this.componentName, ": didn't find a cursor.");
    }

    var canvas = document.querySelector(".a-canvas");

    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
        report("mousedown", e);
        twowaymotion.touching = true;
        this.touchTime = new Date().getTime();
    });
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
        report("mouseup", e);
        twowaymotion.touching = false;
    });

    canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", function (e) {
        this.touch = e;
        report("touches.length: ", e.touches.length);
        if (e.touches.length > 1) {
            report("multitouch: doing nothing");
        } else {
            report("touchstart", e);
            twowaymotion.touching = true;
        }
    });
    canvas.addEventListener("touchend", function () {
        console.log(this.componentName, " touchend");
        twowaymotion.touching = false;
    });
},
update: function() { 
    if (this.el.components["twoway-controls"] !== undefined) {
        this.el.components["wasd-controls"].data.acceleration = this.el.components["wasd-controls"].data.speed;
    }
},
tick: function () {
    if (!AFRAME.utils.device.isMobile() && this.data.nonMobileLoad === false) {
        // this is only for mobile devices, unless you ask for it.
        return;
    }
    if (!this.isPlaying) {
        return;
    }
    var cam = this.el;
    var camrot = cam.getAttribute("rotation");

    if (camrot.x < this.data.threshold) {
        // we are looking down
        if (this.cur !== null && this.cur !== undefined) {
            this.cur.setAttribute("material", "color", "orange");
        }
        if (this.touching === true) {
            cam.components["wasd-controls"].keys["ArrowDown"] = true;
        } else {
            cam.components["wasd-controls"].keys["ArrowDown"] = false;
            cam.components["wasd-controls"].keys["ArrowUp"] = false;
        }
    } else {
        // we are looking forward or up
        if (this.cur !== null && this.cur !== undefined) {
            this.cur.setAttribute("material", "color", this.curcolor);
        }
        if (this.touching === true) {
            cam.components["wasd-controls"].keys["ArrowUp"] = true;
        } else {
            cam.components["wasd-controls"].keys["ArrowDown"] = false;
            cam.components["wasd-controls"].keys["ArrowUp"] = false;
        }
    }
},
pause: function () {
    // we get isPlaying automatically from A-Frame
},
play: function () {
    // we get isPlaying automatically from A-Frame
},
remove: function () {
    if (this.el.components["wasd-controls"] === undefined) {
        this.el.removeAttribute("wasd-controls");
    }
} });
```

Since device orientation permission is not granted on mobile phones, move backward is not working, also, when the audience tries to rotate in a different direction by touching the screen or sliding on screen, it still functions as move forward.

from what I imagine, if there is a simple edit, if the audience touches the screen more than 2 seconds, it start to move forward, if audience just rotate, it will not move forward, since when you slide or touch on the screen to rotate the touching time might not be so long as 2 seconds...

this is the easiest solution that I can imagine under the restriction of without device orientation permission.

or is there any other better way to divide rotate and move forward by touching screen regarding touching time?

Thks!!!!!